# Group together and Sort Odd and Even elements of the Array using Bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bubble-sort

I am trying to make an array where **odd** numbers are sorted in order using *Bubble sort* algorithm on the *left side* of the array, and **even** numbers are sorted in order on the right side of the array.

The output should be like this:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
output: 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 10
```

The first split between even and odd numbers works, and also the sorting of the odd numbers, but the even numbers are not sorted, and I don't know why.

**My Code:**

```
public class ObligOppgave4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
       
        sortEvenAndOdd(a);
        bubbleSortOdd(a);
        bubbleSortEven(a);

        print(a);
    }

    public static void sortEvenAndOdd(int[] a) {

        int l = a.length;
        int v = 0, h = l - 1;

        if (a.length == 0) return;

        while (v <= h) {
            if (((a[v] % 2) == 0) && !((a[h] % 2) == 0)) {
                change(a, v++, h--);
            } else if ((a[v] % 2) == 0) {
                h--;
            } else if (!((a[h] % 2) == 0)) {
                v++;
            } else if (!((a[v] % 2) == 0) && ((a[h] % 2) == 0)) {
                v++;
                h--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void bubbleSortOdd(int[] a) {
        for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n && a[i] % 2 != 0; i++) {
                if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
                    change(a, i - 1, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void bubbleSortEven(int[] a){
        for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n && a[i] % 2 == 0; i++) {
                if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
                    change(a, i ,i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void change(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void print(int[] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that this is the problem:

```
public static void bubbleSortEven(int[] a){
    for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < n && a[i] % 2 == 0; i++)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you have already moved the odd numbers to the beginning of the array, a[1] is pretty much guaranteed to be odd, and so your loop will exit before it does anything because with i=1, a[i]%2 is 1.

You should probably start `sortEven` by scanning through the array to find the first even number, and then starting from there.

Another option would be to do a single bubble sort where you weight the even-ness more than the difference.  Something like:

```
int n1 = a[i-1];
int n2 = a[i];
if (n1%2 != n2%2) {
  if (n1%2 == 0) {
    // n1 is even and n2 is not. Swap them
    change(a, i - 1, i);
  }
} else if (n1 > n2) {
  change(a, i - 1, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can address this problem by sorting by sorting *odd* and *even* parts of the array. That would the solution a bit more concise.

To do that, we can obtain a *pivot* (index which would point either at the rightmost odd number or at the leftmost even number) while splitting the array into two parts.

Then *pivot* index can be used as a boundary while sorting the array.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static void sortEvenAndOdd(int[] arr) {
    int pivot = split(arr);
    sort(arr, pivot);
}

public static int split(int[] arr) {
    int odd = 0;
    int even = arr.length - 1;

    while (true) {
        while (arr[odd] % 2 != 0 && odd < even) odd++;
        while (arr[even] % 2 == 0 && odd < even) even--;
    
        if (odd < even) swap(arr, odd, even);
        else break;
    }
    return odd;
}

public static void sort(int[] arr, int pivot) {
    int hiOdd = arr[pivot] % 2 != 0 ? pivot : pivot - 1; // if pivot points at the Even number - step one index back
    
    for (int odd = 0, even = 0; odd <= hiOdd || arr.length - 1 - even > hiOdd; odd++, even++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < hiOdd - odd; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) swap(arr, i, i + 1);
        }
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > hiOdd + even + 1; j--) {
            
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) swap(arr, j, j - 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int odd, int even) {
    int temp = arr[odd];
    arr[odd] = arr[even];
    arr[even] = temp;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    sortEvenAndOdd(array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```